# Is it possible to load images recovered from a server in runtime into a plane object?

Tags: swift, arkit

I have been asked to build an app that shows a catalog with AR, so what I need to do is pretty simple: when an user chooses a product I must load the image  recovered in base64 from the server into a plane object. Is this possible with swift - arkit ? Or are all the sprites/images/textures required to be previously loaded into the assets folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can definitely download resources from a server, save them to the device (e.g in NSDocumentsDirectory), and then load with the file URL. I do it for a similar use case as yours -at least it sounds so, per the description you gave-

**EDIT**
Here's the relevant code. I use Alamofire to download from the server and [ZIPFoundation](https://github.com/weichsel/ZIPFoundation) for unzipping. I believe that if you just need to download an image, it'll be a bit simpler, probably not needing the unzip part.

```swift
let modelsDirectory = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0]

func loadNodeWithID(_ id: String, completion: @escaping (SCNNode?) -> Void) {
    // Check that assets for that model are not already downloaded
    let fileManager = FileManager.default
    let dirForModel = modelsDirectory.appendingPathComponent(id)
    let dirExists = fileManager.fileExists(atPath: dirForModel.path)
    if dirExists {
        completion(loadNodeWithIdFromDisk(id))
    } else {
        let dumbURL = "http://yourserver/yourfile.zip"
        downloadZip(from: dumbURL, at: id) {
            if let url = $0 {
                print("Downloaded and unzipped at: \(url.absoluteString)")
                completion(self.loadNodeWithIdFromDisk(id))
            } else {
                print("Something went wrong!")
                completion(nil)
            }
        }
    }
}

func loadNodeWithIdFromDisk(_ id: String) -> SCNNode? {
    let fileManager = FileManager.default
    let dirForModel = modelsDirectory.appendingPathComponent(id) 
    do {
        let files = try fileManager.contentsOfDirectory(atPath: dirForModel.path)
        if let objFile = files.first(where: { $0.hasSuffix(".obj") }) {
            let objScene = try? SCNScene(url: dirForModel.appendingPathComponent(objFile), options: nil)
            let objNode = objScene?.rootNode.firstChild()
            return objNode
        } else {
            print("No obj file in directory: \(dirForModel.path)")
            return nil
        }
    } catch {
        print("Could not enumarate files or load scene: \(error)")
        return nil
    }
}

func downloadZip(from urlString: String, at destFileName: String, completion: ((URL?) -> Void)?) {
    print("Downloading \(urlString)")
    let fullDestName = destFileName + ".zip"

    let destination: DownloadRequest.DownloadFileDestination = { _, _ in
        let fileURL = modelsDirectory.appendingPathComponent(fullDestName)
        return (fileURL, [.removePreviousFile, .createIntermediateDirectories])
    }

    Alamofire.download(urlString, to: destination).response { response in
        let error = response.error
        if error == nil {
            if let filePath = response.destinationURL?.path {
                let nStr = NSString(string: filePath)
                let id = NSString(string: nStr.lastPathComponent).deletingPathExtension
                print(response)
                print("file downloaded at: \(filePath)")
                let fileManager = FileManager()
                let sourceURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: filePath)
                var destinationURL = modelsDirectory
                destinationURL.appendPathComponent(id)
                do {
                    try fileManager.createDirectory(at: destinationURL, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil)
                    try fileManager.unzipItem(at: sourceURL, to: destinationURL)
                    completion?(destinationURL)
                } catch {
                    completion?(nil)
                    print("Extraction of ZIP archive failed with error: \(error)")
                }
            } else {
                completion?(nil)
                print("File path not found")
            }
        } else {
            // Handle error
            completion?(nil)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for the answer! So just to confirm, you were able to load a dynamically recovered image on an ARkit object?did you followed any particular tutorial?

Comment: Hi, in my case I needed to load mtl/obj objects on demand. We had the proper .mtl and .obj files along with textures files needed compressed on a zip on the server. We were able to retrieve, uncompress and load on runtime. When I get home I'll edit the answer with some code it, but it was nothing too special nor complicated.